# Django: Picking from QuerySet without slicing it

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset, slice

I have in essential the following models in Django:

```
class Group(models.Model):

class People(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='members')

class Cars(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='vehicles')
```

I want to choose a certain predefined amount of people and cars from some groups. The groups and the corresponding proportions I have saved in lists:

```
groups = [ some groups ]
proportion_pps = [ some positive integer list ]
proportion_cars = [ some positive integer list ]
```

Now the code for my choosing looks like so:

```
for x, group in enumerate(groups):

pps |= People.objects.filter(groups=grop).all().order_by('?')#[:proportion_pps[x - 1]]
crs |= Cars.objects.filter(groups=group).all().order_by('?')#[:proportion_crs[x - 1]]
```

So far so good... But now I run into a "slicing" error when I try:

```
pps.distinct()
crs.distinct()
```

or something like:

```
list_pps = list(pps.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('?'))
```

I see no way around it.

Comment: What is `#[:proportion_pps[x - 1]]` supposed to do?

Comment: I forgot to remove to comment-tag (#), in case you mean that. Otherwise with, say `[:7]`, I just want to choose randomly 7 of the elements in this group.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database used, you can work with [**`.union(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
people = People.objects.none().union(*[
    People.objects.filter(groups=group).all().order_by('?')[:n]
    for group, n in zip(groups, proportion_pps)
])
```

Comment: I work with Postgres in production and djangos sqlite3 now in development. Your suggestion works so far, but now I run into trouble with this: `list_pps = list(pps.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('?'))`, it says `LIMIT/OFFSET not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.`

Comment: @zeus: ordering after the union will be tricky. But it is not necessary anyway if you are using `list`, since then you can simply shuffle at the Python/Django level.

Comment: Thx. But the list_id thing doesn't work without the ordering either: `list_pps = list(pps.values_list('id', flat=True))` runs into the same error

Comment: @zeus: `from random import data; data = [p.pk for p in pps]; shuffle(data)`

Comment: I did `import random` since `from random import data` gives me an error (`Cannot find reference 'data' in 'random.pyi'`). Then your suggestes `data=` command is executed but I run into the same limit/offest error as before.

Comment: @zeus: sorry, it is `from random import shuffle`.

Comment: okay. but still the same limit/offset error... the line `data = [p.pk for p in pps]` does not work

Comment: @zeus: exactly *what* is the error. Here `pps` is just `people` as described in the answer, so without any slicing or `.values_list(...)`/`.order_by('?')`.

Comment: I do exactly what you suggested in the answer above (it is with `.order_by('?')`, but it does also not work when I remove it. Then in the next line I do `data = [p.pk for p in people]`. When I run it, I get from django the error message: `DatabaseError: LIMIT/OFFSET not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.` and it marks this last code line